# Lightroom & Facebook: Can't download comments

Tags: lightroom, facebook

I exported a photo with Lightroom 4 to my Facebook page. In Lightroom I would like to update the comments for an image (at the bottom of the right hand column).

Lightroom takes a bit and then reports with "Can't download comments for this collection."

The image was uploaded to my timeline photos.

What is the error and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The plugin had crashed... Stupid error message in this case. Or maybe it had crashed because of this error. Reloading helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by the Facebook Export Plugin having crashed.

This was the case when I asked this question, and after reloading the plugin, it works now.

Comment: I reloaded the plugin and it still fails in exactly the same way.